# Equivalent to Array.some in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I would like to do the equivalent of Array.some in rails.

Here's an example applied to my usecase which is kind of a more complex `include?` (i want to apply this to `*args`):

```rb
ary = [:a, :b, :c, d: :x, e: :y] # => [:a, :b, :c, { :d => :x, :e => :y }]
search = :e
contained = ary.some { |x|
  x == search || x.try(:key?, search)
} # => true
assert contained, "We should have found #{search}"
```

I could do this with `ary.map` but that would mean go through the whole array and then again test it's contents.
I could also use `ary.drop_while` and verify if it returns an empty array or not but again, i would need to test the result.
I've also seen `ary.bsearch` but there are some strange limitations i don't quite understand about the order of elements.

Have i missed something ? Isn't there an easy way to do that ? i'm using ruby2 and rails 4 (edge).

Comment: Can you give what the output should be?

Comment: I added the output as a comment in the code. `ary.some` should ouput true in that usecase

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Javascript [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is equivalent to Ruby [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

```
["1", "2", "3"].any? { |x| x.to_i == 2 } #=> true
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. I didn't knew of Enumerable ! Thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

If you are really looking for `some?` you might want something like this

```
module Enumerable
  def some?
    self.any? && !self.all?
  end
end
```

This will give you `true` only if some of the elements are set but not all.

Check out the snippet here https://coderwall.com/p/wcgj2w

Comment: `[true].some((e) => e)` is true. Some does not logically or in JS exclude the possibility of all being true.